# Which AR software should I use?

Tags: scenekit, augmented-reality, vuforia, arkit, artoolkit

Good evening everyone!

So I'm currently taking senior design in college and came up with this idea for an Augmented Reality App. Basically, the app will do this:

Display a table with a banner over it and have different objects on that table. The user will be able to select an object to rotate it and possibly gather it's dimensions.

Tapping on the banner will bring the user to a website.

I know of different AR kits like ARkit, ARToolkit, vuforia, scenekit and a few others but wanted to ask people which I should use to achieve these desired results. Thanks in advance!

PS. This app will be developed for iOS.

Comment: What is the AR response here? Do you react to any surface you see? only a table?

Comment: No, the table, banner and items will only show up if you're at a specific location and holding your phone at a certain area. We haven't decided on where to use geo-coordinates or just a QR code. The table will only be to hold the items.

Comment: You cannot get any answers if you do not decide what AR triggering you are using - not all libraries support all kinds... you need to give the specific details - but after you researched yourself and got specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, the best tool for iOS development is ARKit framework in Xcode. This choice is the most sensible not only you'll use Apple ecosystem but because you'll have accompanying frameworks for easy and successful app development: [SceneKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit), [SpriteKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit), [Metal](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal), [Vision](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision), [CoreML](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreml), [AVKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit), etc.

For testing and debugging your AR app you need an Apple smartphone with **A9** chipset or better (iPhone `SE` / `6s` / `7` / `8` / `X` / `Xs` / `Xr`). Each model has a precisely calibrated sensors (gyroscope, accelerometer and magnetometer) what is highly important for robust AR experience.